# How to do "(df1 & not df2)" dataframe merge in pandas?

Tags: python, join, pandas, merge, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes df1 & df2 with common columns/keys (x,y).

I want to merge do a "(df1 & not df2)" kind of merge on keys (x,y), meaning I want my code to return a dataframe containing rows with (x,y) only in df1 & not in df2.

SAS has an equivalent functionality

```
data final;
merge df1(in=a) df2(in=b);
by x y;
if a & not b;
run;
```

Who to replicate the same functionality in pandas elegantly?
It would have been great if we can specify how="left-right" in merge().

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I just upgraded to version 0.17.0 RC1 which was released 10 days ago. 
Just found out that pd.merge() have new argument in this new release called indicator=True to acheive this in pandonic way!!

```
df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['x','y'],how="outer",indicator=True)
df=df[df['_merge']=='left_only']
```

indicator: Add a column to the output DataFrame called _merge with information on the source of each row. _merge is Categorical-type and takes on a value of left_only for observations whose merge key only appears in 'left' DataFrame, right_only for observations whose merge key only appears in 'right' DataFrame, and both if the observation’s merge key is found in both.

http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging

Comment: The correct way to filter a dataframe is as follows, you need to correct the second line of your code: df=df[df['_merge']=='left_only']

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I have fixed it as per your comment.

Comment: I found this link to be extremely helpful for this and other scenarios!  https://kanoki.org/2019/07/04/pandas-difference-between-two-dataframes/

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the index.

If `i1` and `i2` are indices (sets of indices) then `i1.difference(i2)` represent those indices in `i1` and not in `i2`. Then if `df` is a dataframe indexed by the same index type , for instance `i1=df.index` then `pd.DataFrame(index=i1.difference(i2)).join(df)` are those entries in `df` whose index is not in the index `i2`.