# How to do left outer join exclusion in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, A and B, and I want to get those in A but not in B, just like the one right below the top left corner.

[image: The one below the top left]

Dataframe A has columns `['a','b' + others]` and B has columns `['a','b' + others]`. There are no NaN values. I tried the following:

1.

```
dfm = dfA.merge(dfB, on=['a','b'])
dfe = dfA[(~dfA['a'].isin(dfm['a']) | (~dfA['b'].isin(dfm['b'])
```

2.

```
dfm = dfA.merge(dfB, on=['a','b'])
dfe = dfA[(~dfA['a'].isin(dfm['a']) & (~dfA['b'].isin(dfm['b'])
```

3.

```
dfe = dfA[(~dfA['a'].isin(dfB['a']) | (~dfA['b'].isin(dfB['b'])
```

4.

```
dfe = dfA[(~dfA['a'].isin(dfB['a']) & (~dfA['b'].isin(dfB['b'])
```

but when I get `len(dfm)` and `len(dfe)`, they don't sum up to `dfA` (it's off by a few numbers). I've tried doing this on dummy cases and #1 works, so maybe my dataset may have some peculiarities I am unable to reproduce.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: The problem is in the `(~dfA['a'].isin(dfm['a']) | (~dfB['b'].isin(dfm['b']))` expression. For example, if in `dfm` you have `(a=1, b=1), (a=2, b=2)` and in dfA `(a=1, b=2)` then this expression return `False`.

Comment: @user3063243 Got it. I've also posted other attempts I made, none of which are correct. Would you know the correct way to do this?

Comment: nice picture...

Comment: @liang picture not mine though...I got it from somewhere in Google Images

Comment: Related: If you are interested in learning how to correctly merge on columns or index, you can refer to this canonical I've written recently: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101).

Comment: Was struggling with this until I realized that how='left' is NOT 'left-outer', only 'left'.Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676027/how-to-do-df1-not-df2-dataframe-merge-in-pandas)

```
df = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on=['a','b'], how="outer", indicator=True)
df = df[df['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

One liner :

```
df = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on=['a','b'], how="outer", indicator=True
              ).query('_merge=="left_only"')
```

Comment: why how="outer" ?! Why not "left"?

Comment: @pedrambashiri `how="left"` will also work in this case (left outer exclusion)

Comment: @irene thanks, I'd personally prefer left because it's more intuitive and inline with Sql

Answer (score 7):

I think it would go something like the examples in: [Pandas left outer join multiple dataframes on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786490/pandas-left-outer-join-multiple-dataframes-on-multiple-columns)

```
dfe = pd.merge(dFA, dFB, how='left', on=['a','b'], indicator=True)
dfe[dfe['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

Comment: Hi Justin, that would correspond to the top left figure though. It would include the rows they have in common.

Comment: Edit accepted -- this answer also works (and is based on phi's answer above).

Comment: I think this needs to be dfe[dfe['_merge'] == "left_only"]